# Why am I seeing pixelated text when printing images to PDF?

Tags: pdf, printing, images

Every time I print scanned images (like JPG or PNG) to PDF, the text is pixelated, while the source image isn't. No matter what PDF writer I use. Don't have Adobe, but have tried 5-6 other ones with same result.

I can convert these PDF’s back to image with various online tools, and then the full resolution is still present in that image. It is not a PDF-viewer specific issue either.

What is the reason for this? Isn't it possible to display a lossless image in a PDF?

I know there are quality settings during printing and DPI settings, but these do not influence the text pixilation.

[image]

Comment: Make a PDF with Word and you will likely see the result is fine, meaning it is the limit of your scanner causing this.

Comment: A scanner makes pixels, not text. However, you may be able to use OCR to convert the pixels into text, and from that you can get the characters output smoothly.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the quality, I suggest scanning at a higher resolution. Maybe PDF viewers don’t like to do high-quality upsampling.

Comment: How are you creating the PDF ?

Comment: @harrymc I'm using pdf print/writers, like cutepdf, cubepdf, Microsoft Print to PDF, by print function in Irfanview.

Comment: I have never had such a problem, and I have printed to PDF, but never from Irfanview (which I don't use). Have you tried printing from another program, even just a browser?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the low quality outcome of your PDF files is your lack of understanding of the difference between vector images and bitmap images in combination with the internals of the PDF file format.
This results in an unsuitable production process that does not yield the intended outcome.

**Bitmap versus vector fonts**

Computer history started in a bitmap world. Charakters were represented by bitmaps, also called "raster maps". See the following Atari bitmap font:

https://fontmeme.com/fonts/atari-font/

The technical progress in terms of computing power and storage allowed a more beautiful representation of characters by means of so-called vector fonts which for instance describe the letter "d" roughly as a circle that is touched by a straigt line.

Vector fonts can be upsized to the size of the universe without a loss of quality. Bitmap font, regardless how much ressources they consume can be scaled to a level where you see the square pixels.

**Adobe PDF file formats internals**

The PDF file format allows to mix different type of objects, for instance bitmap image using different types of compressions but vector fonts as well.

**Loss compression schemes not suitable for text**

Compression schemes like JPEG or JPEG2000 whose algorithms are implemented within the PDF file format are not suitable for text because their typical lossy application mode creates compressions artefacts that are easily visible.

**Unsuitable PDF production process - printing to a virtual PDF printer**

Most likely your source gets decompressed upon printing providing a giant bitmap to the printer which recompresses this bitmap in a lossy manner using a compression scheme that is good for the image but unsuitable for the text.

You might not see this quality loss with your scanned picture but you see it when looking at your text.

**Solution 1**

Either try the hint of Daniel B. by increasing the scan quality, print it in high resolution and ensuring that the printer settings do not overcompress that image.

**Solution 2**

The other way is to use a PDF editor where you include the image as lossy JPEG and the text as a PNG file.
This way your editor can save both elements (text and picture) separately within the PDF file and is not using one single bitmap like the PDF printer.

Your PDF file would then be decoded by two engines: DCDDecode for the image and JBIG2Decode for the text, see section "raster images" in article
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF

**Solution 3**

If this does not meet your expectations, you would need to scan the text seperately at the highest optical resolution available for you.
Then you would need to do OCR and let some program guess the original font type. If necessary you would need to manually correct the font type.

Keep in mind the production process of your scan:
There is a high quality bit map image und a vector font used by the publisher.
During the printing process the text gets transformed in a high quality bitmap using the vector information. I guess that can be as much as 2540 dpi.

Your comparably poor scan equipment might only able to provide a figure of 600 dpi optically which already reflects a loss of roughly 50% on both the x-axis and the y-axis.

I hope that shines some light on your problem!

Comment: Thanks! Solution 2 may be what I'm after. My use case is to downsize existing pdf documents/books. Like a 300mb file, I export to high-resolution images. I then want a PDF of reasonable size (like 10-40mb). While the images themselves can be downsized substantially without reducing practical readability, the pdf-export always causes visual pixilation. Other case is an old scanned newspaper-article. Here resolution is often critical, meaning anything less than image resolution lowers readability. How to maintain that quality in a PDF export?  What tools are needed for Solution 2? Any free ones?

Comment: Your case description should have been posted in your initial posting! I only know the name of Tesseract software in the linux world. Your question about the newspaper article suggests that you have never used OCR. Scan an article, OCR it into a txt, rtf, ods or doc? file and reprint that one into a PDF file. Zoom into the PDF file to see if the result meets your expectations.

Comment: K J, thank you for pointing out the error in my statement, I have now corrected it.

Answer (score -1):

You can see similar in your choice of image viewer. Based on its current mode. Same image 2 modes, left is as viewer other on right is as an editor and most PDF "readers" are editors.

[image]

IrfanView has various setting for PDF and or images.  Here the PDF image is seen as if it were perfectly scanned (lossless or lossy does not matter). Seen in a PDF viewer, and the same PDF opened in IrfanView will be degraded to larger pixels (it will be Anti-Aliased first but then the Alias is used for PDF viewing).
[image]

**Seen as an image it will be smoothed.**

[image]
A PDF has to define each pixel shape in one form or another in a grid. It could be a skewed grid and there are odd examples. But consider the majority 99%+ will be regular rectangles. Here are 3 pixels wide by 3 pixels high in Googles PDF (image) display.

- https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/colours.pdf

You should see zoomed in or zoomed out exactly the same. Since a PDF must be able to show QRCodes and other pixel based objects without any enhanced smoothing. Image viewers have a different paradigm as they need to interpolate and soften images. What you cannot see unless as an image, is there are 2 BLACK CORNER pixels and only one white square one between them.

[image]

Acrobat does not **always** maintain colour purity so those colours can shift but not the shape (unless told to). We do see the image from same PDF, in that RGB colour profile has the two black corners!
[image]

One advantage is the single pixels can be rotated and disproportionally stretched (These ARE the same above square single pixels). Charts do not have any resolution, simply vectors. The save as image is 3x3 I have placed them as if on a 5x5 white background. We can thus see 2 squares are black. Then the file will be saved incorrectly as 96 DPI, since in the pdf it had a different much lower 3 PPI.

[image]

Image viewers will AVERAGE the pixel via look ahead rules so a gradient is seen to soften harsh edges. Spot the lower left corner is shown correctly as blacker.

[image]

More noticeable in different offerings EXACTLY SAME Image in SAME viewer,
as image on left as PDF on right.

[image]

Comment: Your explanation is more or less correct, but this isn’t about PDF and other file formats. It is only and exclusively about the viewer and what it decides to do. A raster image inside a PDF is still a raster image.

Comment: I don't get exactly what this means.. Shouldn't it be possible to increase the resolution in a PDF so the pixelation is smaller? Or to make it display a flattened image with it's original resolution?

Comment: bretddog,

if your source scan has sufficient resolution (what I doubt) increasing the resolution in the PDF might do the trick but you will pay a lot in addtional storage for the picture component whereas your quality complaint only applies to the text.

Comment: K J, yes you can. You can always reduce the resolution say from 600 dpi to 300 dpi and recreate the PDF file. Obviously you are winning space at the expense of quality.

Comment: K J, there are probably smarter methods for downsizing of pictures than leaving out every second pixel. I am not aware of the algorithms. As for upsizing there is stuff like bicubic interpolation which give better results than doubling pixels.

Comment: I don't know what your term "25% quality loss" means. The storage need drops by 50% from 8 bit colour information to 4 bit, but the possible states to describe colour information is reduced by a factor of 2^(8-4)=2^4=16.

Comment: When you spoke about "8 bit colours" that implied 8 bit per channel to me but for my statement is does not matter anyway. I could not figure out how you came to say "25% quality loss".